# Deploying a Topshelf Console application with TFS CI without clickonce

Tags: tfs, devops

I've developed a Topshelf Console application that needs to run as a service on a Windows Server machine.

I really hate ClickOnce deployment and till now I've done manually building in Release the project then copy the artifacts manually on the machine.

Is there a way I can deploy automatically without publishing with Clickonce?

Also, is there a simple way I can get of the assemblies .config files? They're pretty useless in the production enviorment

I'm using Tfs 2017

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Topshelf Console application. If this need to run as a service on Windows Server machine kind of a service project. You just first need to make sure that has a Build ready. Then instead of using clickonce, you could use the "Copy" task on the Release tab to send the files to the machine that you want, and then run a remote PowerShell to do the installation.

The simplest way is using remote powershell task to achieve the installation. Details about the task please take a look at [Deploy: PowerShell on Target Machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines)

Besides, you could also use **Agent-based deployment** in Release Management. For this, you can install the agent on each of your target servers directly, and then drive rolling deployment to those servers. More details please refer this blog: [Agent-based deployment in Release Management](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deployment-groups/)

It's like using "Machine Groups". You need to install the build and deployment agents on a set of proxy servers in an agent pool and drive deployments to remote target servers.

Comment: Topshelf allows you to run a console project as a service, without the need to manually register the service and so on... btw I'll take a loot at your links